# Validate TextBox based on DropDownList selection

Tags: asp.net, validation

I  need to validate `TextBox` based on Value selected in `DropDownList` controls. I have `asp:TextBox` and `asp:DropDownList` controls.

If user selects `Yes` option from the first dropdown he must type value in text box. How can I validate second box? Thanks for help.

Comment: What do you mean by validate? Validate what? that it's not blank? that it contains only numbers? etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest approach is to set the DropDownList's `AutoPostBack` property to `true` and handle it's `SelectedIndexChanged` event. Then you can Enable/Disable the validator there.

Another approach is to use a `CustomValidator`. This validator is not dependent on a single control. You must write the validation rules on your own. For example the [ClientValidationFunction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction.aspx):

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function ClientValidate(source, arguments) {
        var txt = document.getElementById('TextBox1');
        var ddl = document.getElementById('DropDownList1');
        var decision = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text;
        if(decision=='Yes'){
            arguments.IsValid = txt.value.length > 0;
        }else{
            arguments.IsValid = true;
        }
    }
</script>

<asp:DropDownList id="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Yes</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="False">No</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="BtnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />

<asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1"
       ValidateEmptyText="true"
       ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
       ClientValidationFunction="ClientValidate"
       OnServerValidate="ServerValidation"
       Display="Static"
       ErrorMessage="Please enter text!"
       runat="server"/>
```

Remember to always implement a [OnServerValidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.onservervalidate.aspx) because you should not rely on javascript only(can be disabled). This is easy:

```
void ServerValidation(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args){
    args.IsValid = DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 1 || TextBox1.Text.Length > 0;
}
```

VB.NET

```
Protected Sub ServerValidation(source As Object, args As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs)
    args.IsValid = DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 1 OrElse TextBox1.Text.Length > 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, your answer was the BEST!

Comment: Than you should select as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your submit button.

```
if(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("Yes") && TextBox1.Text.Length==0)
{
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('Enter data in the textbox !');", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `CustomValidator` control, that validates the `TextBox`, from there you'll have to do something like this (assuming C#) in the `CustomValidator_ServerValidate` event handler:

```
bool valid = false;

if (dropDownList.SelectedValue.Equals("yes")) {
   valid = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text);
}

return valid;
```